# Groovy, Add to Map via iteration from yml file

Tags: groovy, yaml, iteration

I need help to read in a yml file and add multiple entries to a map.

If I would add every entry from the yml file manually it would look like this:

```
    Map<String, String[]> map1 = [:]
    map1."TestvalueX" = "0"
    map1."TestvalueY" = "1"
    map1."TestvalueZ" = "4"
```

Output from map1: [TestvalueX:0, TestvalueY:1, TestvalueZ:4]

**Example YML File:**

```
 - TestvalueX: "0"
 - TestvalueY: "1"
 - TestvalueZ: "4"
```

What do I need to add to read in a yml file and add those values to map1 with iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/yamlparse.

[app/src/main/resources/demo.yml](https://github.com/jeffbrown/yamlparse/blob/5d140b72ce7ff0263536792b467d5ec84fb7aadb/app/src/main/resources/demo.yml)

```
info:
  TestValueX: 0
  TestValueY: 1
  TestValueZ: 4
```

[app/src/main/groovy/yamlparse/App.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/yamlparse/blob/5d140b72ce7ff0263536792b467d5ec84fb7aadb/app/src/main/groovy/yamlparse/App.groovy)

```
package yamlparse

import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper

class App {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def slurper = new YamlSlurper()
        def yaml = slurper.parse(App.getResourceAsStream('/demo.yml'))

        Map m = yaml.info
        println m
        assert m.TestValueX == 0
        assert m.TestValueY == 1
        assert m.TestValueZ == 4
    }
}
```

That appears to work:

```
~ $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/yamlparse.git
Cloning into 'yamlparse'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 24, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Total 24 (delta 0), reused 24 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (24/24), 59.84 KiB | 475.00 KiB/s, done.
~ $ 
~ $ 
~ $ cd yamlparse 
yamlparse (main)$ 
yamlparse (main)$ ./gradlew run

> Task :app:run
[TestValueX:0, TestValueY:1, TestValueZ:4]
```

You can write code to iterate over that `Map` and do whatever you like with the data.

**EDIT:**

The question indicates that the Yaml looks like this:

```
- TestValueX: 0
- TestValueY: 1
- TestValueZ: 4
```

When I wrote the original answer I assumed that was a mistake and that you actually have a Map represented in the Yaml but if the Yaml is the question is actually correct, then you could use something like this:

```
def slurper = new YamlSlurper()
def yaml = slurper.parse(App.getResourceAsStream('/demo.yml'))

Map newMap = [:]

for(Map m : yaml) {
    newMap += m
}

println newMap
assert newMap.TestValueX == 0
assert newMap.TestValueY == 1
assert newMap.TestValueZ == 4
```